# How read/calculate the amount of consumed fuel estimated for a travel?

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-consumption

I read some Question like that but the best that i found is to fill the tank and read how many km you can do with that tank and register it.

But i'm developing an application that read information with phone via the OBD2 port.
And i can read type of fuel, engine coolant temp, rpm and speed.
Also i know the distance and duration of user travel and i would calculate an estimation if the tank level can be enough for the travel.

It's possible to do that with the obd2 connected with the phone?
I don't need very precise value but something that let the user if the fuel can't be enough for the travel....
Like a control every 5 min of some parameters that calculate the consume in real time...

I need some particular Pids of OBD besides rpm, speed, fuel level and fuel type?

EDIT

Here a table with all PIDs in mode 01 (real time data) that i can read if the car support related pid... [PIDs table on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs)

EDIT 2

I read that is impossible to get distance traveled from obd2...the only thinks that i can read from it (if my car support it) is the  PID 015E = Engine fuel rate (L/h).
Or i can use the GPS that every tot time (5 min) can find location user and with:
 travel_total_distance - percur_distance_from_GPS(taken by start distance travel - total_distance_travel that is less every time)....

EDIT 3

I try to use the MAF for calculating Fuel Consumption reading this [Link](http://www.windmill.co.uk/obdii.pdf) but my car don't support the MAF PID, 0110 i get NO DATA response, so this formula is not good.
The only think that is supported to all car is the speed car and with this i can use some inverse formula and get distance traveled.

Speed = Distance/Time, so Distance = Speed x Time.... i get time monitoring using phone from start travel to lecture consuming and calculate the percurred km.... anyway with this method the result is obsolete if car is stopped because 0km/h = no consuming :D :D (and it's wrong)...maybe i can set some standard value if the car is stopped but the motor is on.

> instantaneous Distance D = VSS * t/3600
>
> instantaneous Fuel F = 1 /(14.75 * 6.26) * MAF * t/60 instantaneous
>
> MPG = D / F
>
> VSS = Vehicle
>
> Speed Sensor MAF = Mass Air Flow Sensor

Any suggestions?

IMAGE OF APP THAT CALCULATE CONSUMPTION 
[image]

Legenda translations:
Km percorsi = percurred km
Livello carburante = Tank level fuel
Consumo stimato = stimed consumption
Km percorribili = km that the car can percur with the remaining fuel

Comment: Related on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17170646/101039

Comment: Technically the same question, but the answer is just "how to buy and install an ODBII adapter"... https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27882/12030

Comment: The key to the calculation is the value from the Mass Air Flow sensor, the vehicle speed, and the proper air/fuel ratio of your vehicles fuel type.

Comment: Yes they are similar but for me not the same...anyway can be helpfull for some steps of my question

Comment: Here is an offhand comment that is not a specific answer, however:  If you have a phone that speaks "bluetooth" to an OBD adapter, it most certainly has a GPS capability.  I have not been a "developer" for decades, but if you have access to the phone API for the GPS data, most of your hard work will be done.  I suspect the interface between that core API and your code would be the hardest part.  As others have implied, this mitigates all the "tire pressure/driving style/coasting/parked running" details and becomes a simple question of * calculated GPS distance/fuel % delta*

Comment: Yes, with Google Apis i try to get a Percurred distance in km and with %of tank loss i calculate the km/% that can be converted in Km/l or Km/Kg for CNG

Comment: The problem occur when there is a lot of traffic and a lot of queue in the street....with this all the formula become obsolete because the car consume fuel but distance traveled is 0.... there is a big problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things.

- The car knows how much fuel is left in the tank, that's what the fuel gauge is for, and many (but not all) vehicles relay this info through the OBD2 connector.
- You can also get the mileage through the OBD2 connector.
- Then, do math.

One of my vehicles has a fuel mileage thing included, and I was surprised at how much the instantaneous fuel efficiency changed from coasting to hard acceleration. This information will be useless for what you are intending to do. Instead, just get how much total fuel has been used (either from the last fillup or from the last app reset), just by:

- when you check the fuel level, if it went up, the car got refueled. Save this new fuel level for your next calculations, and store the previous fuel consumed tally if you plan on using it later. Also save the odometer reading taken at this time.
- if the fuel level went down, the car has been driven. Subtract the current fuel level from the last saved fuel level, that's how much fuel was used. If you are resetting your calculations every fillup, use this number. If you are continuing your calculations from the last time the app was reset, add this amount to the previous fuel tally (but don't overwrite the previous fuel tally).
- get the odometer reading and subtract it from the odometer reading at last refueling, that's your distance driven since the last refueling. Also subtract the current odometer reading from the last time the app was reset, that is your trip distance driven.
- Do simple math to get fuel efficiency since last fillup and last app reset (distance / fuel used = MPG, fuel used / distance * 100 = L/100 km)
- If the user inputs the distance needing to be driven for the entire
  trip, your app can calculate the amount of fuel needed (at the start
  of the trip), and update this figure every time you take a reading.
  (miles left / MPG = gallons needed, km left * L/100 km / 100 = litres needed; if the amount of fuel needed is bigger than current fuel level, you will need to make at least 1 more fuel stop)

Don't worry about rpms, uphills, downhills, traffic, headwind, tailwind, sidewind, nowind, rain, snow, hot, dry, good tires, bad tires, stroke length, bore size, spark plug gap, or how long since the driver's last eaten meatloaf. These things affect fuel efficiency, yes, but they are not things you can calculate. There are more things affecting fuel efficiency than the OBD2 connector can tell you about. Just use the fuel used and the distance travelled.

Comment: Hahahahha sir your are the BEST.
I'm italian so i need to understand better what you say using some traslater for technical parts and i will try your suggestion.

But the only problem about level fuel is the type.
Because i can only read the % of fuel tank but not the total liters or Kg for CNG and GPL.... have some suggestion?
Or only hands write from user the the level of inputed fuel?

Comment: Sorry can you explain what is MPG?
And from obd2 i can't read mileage (for me km percurred)...only the on board car computer can manage Km (distance).... or i'm wrong?

Comment: @Dario "MPG" is the acronym for "miles per gallon," the measure of fuel-efficiency using Imperial units (miles and gallons). "Mileage" is a generic term that means "distance travelled," it can be in miles or km, depending on the computer. :)

Comment: @Dario If you only have the percentage of fuel tank, then require the user to input the size of the fuel tank when they setup a profile for their vehicle. You can probably get a serial number from thew OBD2 connector so people can have multiple profiles in the app, one for each vehicle. :)

Comment: @ tlhIngan Yes i'm adding some user input for some technical car data like:
Fuel tank, max km traveled with one full tank (if know)...
I don't understand clearly what pids i need from obd2 for my consumption calculation.... i edit my post with a link that contain a table of pids..

Comment: @ tlhIngan maybe the Pid that can calculate the MPG is the 015E = Engine fuel rate (L/h)... but there isn't nothing about Km/l and nothing that give me distance traveled from obd port as you see the list pids....

Maybe i can use phone gps for read distance traveled but it is very inaccurate and if you know some way for read distance traveled from obd that ca be good

Comment: @Dario If it's not on the list, then it is a non-standard PID, meaning each manufacturer will be doing it differently.

Comment: What do you think about this post @tlhIngan?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170646/fuel-consumption-from-obd2-port-parameters

It's on the list of PIDs that i edit in my post, but my car say NO DATA with CNG and with Gasoline too

Comment: @Dario I don't like it. It assumes that everything is working perfectly. If your tires are inflated at the wrong pressure, the VSS value is incorrect. And if you run the engine while the car is not moving, that formula says that you are not using any fuel at all, and that's a lie.

Comment: @ tlhIngan ok clear and right...as you say in your post "Don't worry about rpms, uphills, downhills, traffic, headwind, tailwind, sidewind, nowind, rain, .."

What do you think about Km/% ... i can read the % of tank fuel but not dimension, so i would calculate the consumption Km per % so i know that the car can run 20Km and consume 2% of fuel input tank.... can be good?
With this i don't need to calculate the kg(CNG) or liters(diesel and gasoline) but i have only one unit of measurement (%)..

Comment: @Dario Sure, that would allow you to calculate range. But I think people would like the know their actual L/100 km. Just ask the user what the fuel tank size is when they create a profile.

Comment: in a few days i implement the code and let you know what happend and when all works i check your post.
Anyway thanks for your time for now....
If you know some method from get percurred Km withouth GPS i'm here xD

Comment: The problem occur when there is a lot of traffic and a lot of queue in the street....with this all the formula become obsolete because the car consume fuel but distance traveled is 0.... there is a big problem...so the best way is to find some way to calcolate consuming with obd port :(

Comment: Hi King... now i have some data read but the result don't are same like the stimed consumption in the bookcar... they say that my car consuming 6,4 liters of CNG with 100Km... but my app with 10Km had a stimed consumption with 2,26Km/l ... and it's not right because 100Km : 6,4L = 10,86Km : xL (0,69L) ... but my stimed consumption is near to 5 liters.....

The app Torque is more precise....i think that they use another method for calculate consumption...any idea?
I update with a screenshoot of the app

Answer (score -1):

Was going to add as a comment but run out of space...

Interesting idea, probably should have patented it before putting it in the public domain, can see this being useful to GPS peeps/MAP peeps.

Anyways I am see this a number of separate needs:

1) tank size and engine size, you need to basically be able to estimate used per stroke and how many strokes you have in the tank.

2) Need to be able to estimate gas used at certain RPM.

3) Need to know how far you get with certain RPMs for a certain quantity of gas.

4) Need to add fuzzy factor for terrain (hills, etc), weather (snow, wind, etc), gas type (high octain, etc), engines running off spec (leaks, etc).

5) Need to know actual gas left in tank (don't have a way of figuring this out) so the app can use this and the above calcs to let you know if you need to fill up. How are you planning to address this?

If it were me I would look at average driving habits (50/60kph in town + 100/120 highway) and get average RPMS at these speeds, and actual measured gas consumption per engine size. You would need to sample many cars - perhaps crowd source it. That is unless there is already published data on this.

Then you have a way of taking the engine size, RPM and historical average data and infer gas use real time. If you hold down the accelerator, the gas use calc will increase and the estimated travel. Sounds like an interesting project, have fun.

Comment: I'm not sure how this gives the OP information about the PID they're requesting? (No, I didn't download you, but pretty sure this is the reason you were.)

Comment: OP is a software developer clearly (see profile). So am I. So was giving my answer from perspective of developer to developer. I don't mind down votes, just giving my opinion. As I mention on outlet, was gonna just post as a comment because I did not have an answer. Would you channel pros have recommended sending private IM to OP instead?

Comment: It's recommended for chatter outside answering the question to take it to a chat room, whether the Pitstop, or creating your own.

Comment: Hi Chris, i don't need patent because a lot of people had same idea like mine :D :D .... the problem is how to calculate the best consume during the travel.
My idea is time query from obd and perform calculation for real time data.
About fuel level, yes you can see the % of fuel with PID 015E if i'm right.