# How to arrive to an instantaneous estimation of fuel consumption using OBD2 ELM327 parameters

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-consumption, fuel-tank

**Problem details**
Hi my friends, i'm working on a project in vehicles field, and i want to make a system to estimate number of fuel litters consumed in each second or any time unit, using the OBD2 ELM327 and it's parameters like: mass air flow, speed, fuel trim percent...etc.
i tried many equations and i didn't find a good result, i also faild to get the fuel level from my car.
so i want to ask if any body have an idea how to calculate fuel consumption.
**My first try**
the first try i used this operation:
fuel_consumption(gals/second) = (((Mass_Air_Flow(g/s) / 14.7) / 454) / 6.701).
from this reference : [Real-Time Fuel Consumption Monitoring](https://www.windmill.co.uk/fuel.html)
**My second try**
The second time i found this equation but in my vehicle some times return the short fuel trim with a negative value, (can i process it ?)
[image: See this equation]

So i'm asking if there is any other way for my problem to get the instantaneous estimation of fuel consumption in litters/second

Speed it is the vehicle speed in km/h
maf is the value of mass air flow sensor
F1 and F2 is the values of long term, and short term fuel trim

**Overview of my data**
[image: See this image]

Finally, thank you..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How read/calculate the amount of consumed fuel estimated for a travel?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48845/how-read-calculate-the-amount-of-consumed-fuel-estimated-for-a-travel)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Comment: Solar Mike, sorry no.